# How to move a function outside of Gruntfile.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a function **my_function** in Gruntfile.js as following:

```
// Gruntfile.js

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    var config = my_function(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig(config);
};

function my_function(grunt) {
    //some code
    return config;
}
```

It works perfectly but now I want to move the function to another file, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an another module.
func.js

```
module.exports = (function() { console.log(1); })();
```

gruntfile

```
var myFunc = require("./func.js");
```

Comment: I already tried this method, but got error "Error: Cannot find module 'my_function_file.js'"

Comment: `require("./func.js");` path must be relative to you working directory, where is located gruntfile. I have updated unswer.

Comment: Can't believe that's it, I spent whole day searching and tried every method I could find..., thank you so much!

Comment: When you write require("func.js"), this will search the module in node_modules directory.